# Uno Platform: Droid Project, duplicating all code

Tags: xamarin, uno-platform

I am trying to learn [Uno](https://platform.uno/), so I followed the Hello World project steps, but I am getting 5.116 error messages in the Droid project from generated files.

Apparently, the files are being duplicated, one time in "obj\Debug\90\Resource.designer.cs" and another time in "obj\Debug\90\designtime\Resource.designer.cs".

Note, this error occurs with the project without any changes, right from the wizard.

Already try to update NuGet packages, create the csproj manually, change the android version, delete bin/obj folders to re-create on next build, execute in VS2017 and 2019.

Here, a zip file with the whole solution: https://puu.sh/EXt5V/530c5629d3.zip

Comment: I have test the zip file on VS 2019. No error. You could check the result with screenshot. https://imgur.com/UcpzDmf Try the following steps. If the way that delete the obj and bin file, clean and rebuild does not work, try to do this in a new project, if you still have the error, run the project directly. If it does not work, repair the VS and do it again.

Comment: "delete the obj and bin file, clean and rebuild": The errors persists... "try to do this in a new project": The errors persists... "run the project directly": This seems to work a couple of times, but, at some random point, rust run does not work anymore! "Repair the VS": Repaired, but the error persisted...

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser can you go in "Help -> About Visual studio" and Copy the info ? You must be missing something. I opened your test solution in VS2019, pressed F5 and it worked for me.

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser You could run the project, it means the error would not affect you. Sometimes i get the error in my project error list as well. Normally, we use the ways in my previous comment to check. It does not matter.

Comment: @matfillion Here is my about file: https://puu.sh/EYmFU/d1e03371b6.txt

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I think you don't understand what I said, a couple times means that, after I put some logic on a test project (And I did it), I cannot run it anymore... Also, I cannot accept invest on a platform that works in such a  precarious way... So, unless a real answer is given, I cannot upvote your answer...

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser I seem to have a very similar install. Another idea I have is you Android SDKs and Tools. Do you have latest Android Build tools checked? something like this ? https://imgur.com/hFcEbcE 
Also make sure Extras/Android Support Repository is checked (at the bottom)

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser other idea is sometimes changing the API Level for android requires to reboot VisualStudio or it messes up the resources. Did you change the API level ?
And last I idea is related to FastDeployment. You can try disabling it (TestApp.Droid, right-click -> Properties -> Android Options -> uncheck Use Fast Deployment)

Comment: @EvertonElvioKosere Another way, you could try to delete the code in Resource.designer.cs file not delete the file. And then rebuild the project. Have a try.

Comment: @matfillion Some of the items of the Android SDK was different... I updated all to match your text, but the error persists... I also updated the VS2019 to the new update released yesterday...

Comment: @matfillion ITried to change the Android Version... And the error persists, but in a different folder, so, i deleted the project and created a clean one.

Comment: @matfillion I tried to uncheck the Fast Deployment, but the error persists...

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT If I needed to manually clean every file from the obj file every time I rebuild the solution, I prefer dont use at all... Unless this is a test of an actual path to the uni framework...

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser are you using any visual studio extensions or plugins ?

Comment: No... Is a clean VS 2019 install... But at this point I will let uno go... And archive similar results using Shared Class Libraries, Blazor and Xamarin forms...

Comment: @EvertonElvioKoser I'm afraid your problem lies in Xamarin.Android so you might face the same problem with Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I have test the zip file on VS 2019. No error. You could check the result with screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Avu.jpg

Try the following steps. If the way that delete the obj and bin file, clean and rebuild does not work, try to do this in a new project, if you still have the error, run the project directly. If it does not work, repair the VS and do it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your exact issue, but I think it is related to a Xamarin.Android problem with DesignTime resources. You can try to disable them.

1. Unload the Android project
2. In the project file and add following line to under the first PropertyGroup tag:

```
<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
```

3. Reload the project
4. Re-build the project